# how to open a mdb file, that is already opened by some other user?

Tags: ms-access, sharing

I have created an Access file with forms and report and put it in a shared drive with full access rights. But when one user open the Access file, another user can not open the file. He clicks on the file, but no response comes... while I, at the server, am able to open it at anytime.
I am stuck. This Project is for all the users, all of them need to access the mdb file at the same time. How could it be done.

I have a lot of hope. Hope you guys help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Access as the data storage for a true multi-user system. Move to a real SQL Server (or at least the desktop engine) instead.

Comment: If concurrent use is becoming an issue you should seriously consider moving to SQL server, even one of the express editions. Seriously.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the above two comments.  I have clients with 20-25 users in a proper split environment who are happily running with an Access backend.

Comment: I also agree with the comments suggesting Access is not viable for multi-user systems. Those comments reflect ignorance and/or bigotry, not real-world experience.

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that it is not viable for a multi user system. Clearly the split FE/BE pattern works well for small businesses. Just that SQL server is better in that scenario if users are starting to get problems with concurrent access, and is vastly more scalable. Either way is better than a single mdb on a network share. I am not an Access MVP like Tony & David, but I'm not an Access-basher either and I don't mean to come across as one. Access has its place and is the right tool for the job for a lot of small businesses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the database splitter wizard to split your database into separate front end and back end components.  Your forms and reports should remain in the front end.  And the back end should contain only tables, indexes, and relationships.  In the front end, your "tables" will actually be links to the back end tables.

Then use Tony Toews' Auto FE Updater (http://www.autofeupdater.com/) so that each user will work from their own copy of the front end database.

The approach that you're using now ... allowing multiple users to directly open the same mdb stored on a network share ... is asking for trouble.  In addition to the problem you're seeing now, that approach dramatically increases the risk of database corruption.  Don't do that!

Comment: See the "Splitting your app into a front end and back end Tips" page at http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/ for more info.  BTW the Auto FE Updater is free.

Comment: +1 for your Auto FE updater Tony! I will give it a try on my users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of your users is now opening the file in Exclusive mode?

Comment: This can also happen unintentially for reasons that have never quite been clear to me.